# Find the limit of the sequence $x_n = \dfrac{\lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor 3^2x \rfloor + ... + \lfloor (2n-1)^2x \rfloor}{n^3}$.

Tags: calculus, limits

I am given the following sequence:

$$x_n = \dfrac{\lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor 3^2x \rfloor + ... + \lfloor (2n-1)^2x \rfloor}{n^3}$$

where $n \ge 1$ and I am asked to find this limit.

I don't know how to approach this. I know that:

$$x - 1 < \lfloor x \rfloor \le x$$

But I don't see how should I apply it in this context.

Comment: you can use it to sandwich the limit between two other limits, both of which will be the same

Comment: Try [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3160362/lim-limits-n-to-inftyx22x-dots-n2x-over-n3/3160393#3160393)

Comment: @rtybase Thanks for linking that page. It was really useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x-1 < \lfloor x \rfloor \le x$ applies for all $x$, we can see that $$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \left((2i-1)^2x-1\right)}{n^3} < x_n \le \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (2i-1)^2x}{n^3}$$

Simplifying the sums, this yields $$\frac{\frac{x}{3}n(4n^2-1) - n}{n^3} < x_n \le \frac{\frac{x}{3}n(4n^2-1)}{n^3}$$

Finally, this can be simplified to $$\frac{4n^2x-x-3}{3n^2} < x_n \le \frac{4n^2x-x}{3n^2}$$

$$\frac{4x}{3} - \frac{x+3}{3n^2} < x_n \le \frac{4x}{3} - \frac{x}{3n^2}$$

Since $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x}{n^2} = 0$, we get that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = \frac{4x}{3}$$

Comment: How did you simplify those sums? I didn't understand that part.

Comment: I used $\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$.